# How to add read more button and in that when we touch it show some extra text?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis voluptates quaerat voluptas quidem reiciendis, non maiores a, autem nobis, quos quisquam earum! Incidunt, nisi unde, facere atque eveniet eum ut odit quisquam hic consectetur animi tenetur nihil enim repudiandae soluta laudantium laborum est quis iste harum consequuntur. Illum, nemo explicabo!
        
    </p>
<button type="submit">Read more</button>
</body>
</html>
```

First I take a paragraph and a button. When we click at the button it more text

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+read+more+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Where does the more text come from? Already loaded and hidden or still on the server?